# Initial Navigation on CloudFront redirects to home

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby, amazon-cloudfront, static-site

I have a gatsbyjs site which I host using S3 and CloudFormation.

If I navigate to the `/blogs` page, I always end up on the root page first. Navigation works fine afterwards.

On my machine using either `gatsby develop` or `gatsby build && gatsby serve` works. I can than naviagte to localhost:9000/blogs and see the blogs page.
When I deploy everything to a S3 Bucket (+CloudFront and a Domain) and navigate to [quadroid.net/blogs](https://quadroid.net/blogs) I end up on the root page of my homepage.

I could not find any redirect in the networking tab of chrome.
Refreshing the page when viewing `/blogs` does again navigate to home.

Any clues why this might happen?

EDIT
The deployment is done using `amplify publish --yes --invalidateCloudFront`.

Comment: Try clear the CloudFront cache first.

Comment: @jellycsc Hi, The deployment includes cloudfront invalidation
`amplify publish --yes --invalidateCloudFront`

Answer (score 0):

You need to set your Bucket to be public. And set the Origin and Origin Group. It's working for me.

Reference: [public-s3-cloudfront-origin](https://cloudsploit.com/remediations/aws/cloudfront/public-s3-cloudfront-origin)